# data‑cart‑item‑add listener firing multiple times

Tags: bigcommerce

When using this hook and adding a product to the cart it fires multiple times - for each 'add to cart' button on the page. So the item quantity gets multiplied.

```
addProductToCart() {
    utils.hooks.on('cart-item-add', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

How do I change that to only fire once for the button clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I used the hook outside of 'addProductToCart' and it works fine. I'm good now. - Cheers